# Can i show the location name suggestions for AutoCompleteTextView from service in android?

Tags: android

I am using AutoCompleteTextView to show the suggestions for my search area. It is displaying city names which are coming form the server. I stored them in array and gave that array to adapter. But some time the services is giving thousands of city name. To load these city names my application will take 4-5 minutes. So i want an alternative to do that. Now my theme is getting city names from some existed api's like Google api, etc.. But i did not get any example for that. I find some applications are using name generator to generate name of cities and products.

Please provide me a way to display city names as suggestion from any existed api's or suggest me is there any libraries to generate names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried before this with any code?

Comment: Thank you for your response.I tried with my server data but not with other api's.

Answer (score 2):

the following example may help u

in this example following action perform

1> insert text in edittext box eg mu

2> click button

3> then insert city name which is starting from mu

this is link http://pastie.org/8544200